# Multiple jQuery Pop-up Forms: Connect a href to <form> divs for user input

Tags: forms, jquery-ui, popup

I'm working on a digital textbook feature that would allow the student to click a link to open up a simple div form for them to input their answer to that specific question. The pop-up form is just simple HTML/CSS with some jQuery UI to hide, show, and make it draggable. Here's the twist. I've got multiple questions that each need to be attached to a unique div. No problem, I thought. I'll just set each a href to link back to a unique ID that I've assigned within the DIV. Problem is, I can't seem to target the proper DIV with its corresponding a href. Instead the same set of questions appear no matter which link is clicked. This seems super simple and I'm probably overcomplicating it. What can I do here?

HTML:

```
<div id="draggable" class="messagepop pop">
  <form method="post" id="new_message" action="/answers">
    <p><label for="body">What type of person is Carsten?</label><textarea rows="15" name="body" id="body" cols="55"></textarea></p>
    <p><label for="body">How do you know?</label><textarea rows="15" name="body" id="body" cols="55"></textarea></p>
    <p><center><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit" id="message_submit"/> or <a id="hide" href="#">Cancel</a></center></p>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="draggable" class="messagepop pop">
  <form method="post" id="new_message" action="/answers">
    <p><label for="body">What can you learn about an active volcano from the photograph?</label><textarea rows="15" name="body" id="body" cols="55"></textarea></p>
    <p><center><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit" id="message_submit"/> or <a id="hide" href="#">Cancel</a></center></p>
  </form>
</div>

<a href="#" id="show">Draw Conclusions</a>&emsp;What kind of person is Carsten? How do you know?
<a href="#" id="show">Use Text Features</a>&emsp;What can you learn about an active volcano from the photograph?
```

Where the first a href needs to open the first div and the second a href opens the second div, etc., etc.

CSS:

```
.messagepop {
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
cursor:default;
display:none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
text-align:left;
width:394px;
height: 335px;
z-index:50;
padding: 25px 25px 20px;
background-color: #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
border-color: #E5E5E5 #DBDBDB #D2D2D2;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.show').click(function() {
    if ( !$(this).next('div').is(':visible') ) {
        $(".messagepop").slideFadeToggle();
        $(this).next('div').slideFadeToggle();
    }
});

$('.hide').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideFadeToggle();});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, "fast", easing, callback);};

$(function() {
$("#draggable").draggable();});
```

Comment: You should not use the same id for different elements.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've been mixing and matching solutions. The show and hide calls are there now. That part had been working, but the problem is that I need the links to correspond to their proper div. The same id just refers to the jQuery draggable function. It's the only way I could figure to call that on multiple divs.

Comment: That's what class is for. An id is (should be) unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your advice and for ironing out my poorly written method. It seems you've got it working.

I've since discovered a jQuery Mobile solution that is much easier than what I was trying to pull together.

For future viewers, it would simply look like this.

```
<a href="#popup1" class="popuplink" data-rel="popup">Draw Conclusions</a>
<a href="#popup2" data-rel="popup">Use Text Features</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popup1" class="ui-content" data-position-to="window">
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <p>What kind of person is Carsten?</p>
    <input type="text"/>
    <p>How do you know?</p>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="popup2" class="ui-content" data-position-to="window">
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <p>What can you learn about an active <mark><b>volcano</b></mark> from the photograph?</p>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

The logic here makes a lot more sense to me and there's the added benefit of ensuring it will work properly on mobile devices. Then if you want to make it draggable, just drop in:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".ui-content").draggable();
});
</script>
```

And then if you want it to be draggable on mobile (remember, jQuery UI isn't natively supported on mobile), you'll have to call up a hack of sorts. I like [Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/).

You may run into issues with form inputs when using Draggable combined with Touch Punch, but that's a story for another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ebNsz/

I've set id:s for the question-div:s and target them with the 'href' attribute in the 'a' elements. Not sure what you wanted to do with the 'slideFadeToggle' function, so i used 'fadeToggle' instead.

HTML:

```
<div id="q1" class="messagepop">
  <form method="" id="form1" action="/answers">
    <label for="answer1">What type of person is Carsten?</label><textarea name="answer1" class="answer"></textarea>
    <label for="answer2">How do you know?</label><textarea name="answer2" class="answer"></textarea>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /> or <a class="close" href="">Cancel</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="q2" class="messagepop">
  <form method="" id="form2" action="/answers">
    <label for="answer1">What can you learn about an active volcano from the photograph?</label><textarea name="answer1" class="answer"></textarea>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /> or <a class="close" href="">Cancel</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<p><a href="#q1" class="toggle">Draw Conclusions</a>&emsp;What kind of person is Carsten? How do you know?</p>
<p><a href="#q2" class="toggle">Use Text Features</a>&emsp;What can you learn about an active volcano from the photograph?</p>
```

jQuery: (jsFiddle doesn't support .draggable(), so i commented out the first line and added the second.)

```
$(function() {

    /* $("div.messagepop").draggable().hide();*/
    $("div.messagepop").hide();

    $("a.toggle").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var targetpop = $(this).attr('href');        
        $(targetpop).siblings("div.messagepop").fadeOut();
        $(targetpop).fadeToggle();
    });

    $("a.close").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("div.messagepop").fadeToggle();        
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.messagepop {
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 50%;
z-index: 50;
margin-left: -197px;
text-align: center;
width: 394px;
height: 335px;
padding: 25px 25px 20px;
background-color: #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
border-color: #E5E5E5 #DBDBDB #D2D2D2;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}

label {
display: block;
}

textarea {
width: 75%;
height: 5em;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```